# how to chop of a text in a certain length with php?

Tags: php, string-concatenation

i wanna get some field values from database and present them on html.

but some of them are longer than the div width so i wanted to chop if of and add 3 dots after them if they are longer than lets say 30 characthers.

```
windows vs mac os x-> windows vs m...
threads about windows vista -> threads about win...
```

how can i do that?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262201/cut-strings-short-php

Comment: (*sidenote*) `chop()` strips whitespace (or other characters) from the end of a string. A more appropriate term for your usecase is *truncate*. The three dots are actually called *ellipsis* and are technically just one character: `…` or `&hellip;` as an HTML entity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you need to perform this kind of functionality more than once, consider this function:

```
function truncate($string, $limit, $break = '.', $pad = '...')
{
    // return with no change if string is shorter than $limit
    if(strlen($string) <= $limit) return $string;

    // is $break present between $limit and the end of the string?
    if(false !== ($breakpoint = strpos($string, $break, $limit)))
    {
        if($breakpoint < strlen($string) - 1)
        {
            $string = substr($string, 0, $breakpoint) . $pad;
        }
    }

    return $string;
}
```

Usage:

```
echo truncate($string, 30);
```

Answer (score 1):

Judging by your examples you don't seem to care about preserving words, so here it is:

```
if (strlen($str) > 30)
{
    echo substr($str, 0, 30) . '...';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Smarty, you can use the [**truncate**](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/fr/language.modifier.truncate.tpl) modifier.

```
{myLongText|truncate:30:'...':true}
```

BTW, such kind of function should exist in any decent template engine.

Answer (score -2):

Check out [wordwrap()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php), that should be what you're looking for.